# How to do math with NSNumbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I keep getting an error that says

"  Initializing 'NSNumber *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'double'  "

Heres my equation:

```
{ 
NSNumber *nAt3 = (-1*(([RSSIvalue integerValue] - [aValue integerValue])/(10*log10(3))));
}
```

RSSIvalue and aValue are both objects of type NSNumber.

How do i declare nAt3 in a way that will make this work?

Answer (score 5):

just one more character

```
{ 
NSNumber *nAt3 = @(-1*(([RSSIvalue integerValue] - [aValue integerValue])/(10*log10(3))));
}
```

using `@()` to convert number to `NSNumber`. e.g. `@(1+1)` give you something like `[NSNumber numberWithInt:(1+1)]`

Comment: Just to add to this solution, an explanation of compiler directives using @, http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/

Answer (score 3):

You can't do math with `NSNumber`'s, but you can do math with the numbers they represent. That is why you have two calls to `integerValue` - that moves you from the domain of `NSNumber`'s to the domain of `NSInteger`, and then you do the math.

What is missing is moving back from numbers to `NSNumber` - with modern syntax do can just enclosed your expression in `@(...)`, which in your case is shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(...)]`.

Answer (score 2):

The result of your calculation is a double, so you need to convert that to an NSNumber before assigning it to nAt2:

```
NSNumber *nAt3 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(-1*(([RSSIvalue integerValue] - [aValue integerValue])/(10*log10(3))))];
```

Comment: Thanks rdelmar but bryan beat ya to it